# Problem with loading data from the XML

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have XML file

```
<contact>
<title>Flex</title>
<title>Flash</title>
<title>Illustrator</title>
<title>Photoshop</title>
<title>Dreamweawer</title>
<title>Flash player</title>
```

in my application is tilelist which loads data from XML
why I can not take the name of the selected item in the TextInput?

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" applicationComplete="contactsService.send()">
<fx:Declarations>
<mx:HTTPService id="contactsService"
                resultFormat="e4x"
                url="contacts.xml"/>
</fx:Declarations>


<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.ItemClickEvent;
        import mx.events.ListEvent;

        public function SomthingSelected ():void {
            txt.text = this.tileList.selectedItem.@title;   
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:TileList id="tileList"
             dataProvider="{contactsService.lastResult.title}"
             columnCount="4"
             columnWidth="125"
             rowCount="2"
             rowHeight="100"
             verticalScrollPolicy="on" 
             itemClick="SomthingSelected ()"/>

<s:TextInput x="10" y="223" id="txt" text="Sergii hi"/>
```

Help me please (

Comment: Is your contact tag closed? Also the '@' notation is for attributes, not node values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify the tag as the data is already there.  Try doing this:

```
private function SomthingSelected ():void {
            txt.text = this.tileList.selectedItem.toString();   
        }
```